# FlywaySqlException: Unable to check whether table "flyway_schema_history" exists

Tags: spring, flyway, google-cloud-spanner-emulator

I'm trying to build a spring application that is using Spanner. The build was working properly until I bumped the spring version to 2.6.2 and then I started to see this error.

this is part of how I configured the spring flyway

```
spring.flyway.url=${spring.datasource.url}
spring.flyway.driver-class-name=${spring.datasource.driver-class-name}
spring.flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration,classpath:com/org/project
spring.flyway.table=FlywaySchemaHistory
```

Has anyone seen this before?

```
2022-04-05T15:30:27.085 ERROR [    Test worker] o.f.c.i.jdbc.PlainExecutionTemplate      : Failed to execute operation in non-transactional context. Please restore backups and roll back database and code! []
2022-04-05T15:30:27.086  WARN [    Test worker] onfigReactiveWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'flywayInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/flyway/FlywayAutoConfiguration$FlywayConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.flywaydb.core.internal.exception.FlywaySqlException: Unable to check whether table `FlywaySchemaHistory` exists
----------------------------------------------------------
SQL State  : null
Error Code : 3
Message    : INVALID_ARGUMENT: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: Unrecognized name: TABLE_TYPE; Did you mean TABLE_NAME? [at 10:24]
            (CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE' ELSE TABLE_TYPE...
                       ^ - Statement: 'SELECT TABLE_CATALOG AS TABLE_CAT, TABLE_SCHEMA AS TABLE_SCHEM, TABLE_NAME,
       CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE' ELSE TABLE_TYPE END AS TABLE_TYPE,
       NULL AS REMARKS, NULL AS TYPE_CAT, NULL AS TYPE_SCHEM, NULL AS TYPE_NAME,
       NULL AS SELF_REFERENCING_COL_NAME, NULL AS REF_GENERATION
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS T
WHERE UPPER(TABLE_CATALOG) LIKE @p1
  AND UPPER(TABLE_SCHEMA) LIKE @p2
  AND UPPER(TABLE_NAME) LIKE @p3
  AND (
            (CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE' ELSE TABLE_TYPE END) LIKE @p4
        OR
            (CASE WHEN TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' THEN 'TABLE' ELSE TABLE_TYPE END) LIKE @p5
    )
ORDER BY TABLE_CATALOG, TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME'
 []
2022-04-05T15:30:27.110 DEBUG [    Test worker] com.ea.maxis.pubsub.PublisherClient      : Publisher terminated []
```